# Alsa records double speed

Tags: audio, linux-device-driver, alsa, i2s

Disclaimer : I posted for the same issue (with a different point of view) [here](https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/IMX8MM-SPH0645-I2S-microphone-speed-up-recordings/m-p/1250341)

I use a [SPH0645 I2S microphone](https://community.nxp.com/pwmxy87654/attachments/pwmxy87654/imx-processors/171279/1/ph0645lm4h-b-datasheet-rev-c-1525723.pdf) with a [custom driver](https://community.nxp.com/pwmxy87654/attachments/pwmxy87654/imx-processors/171279/2/003-sph0645-driver.patch).

It seams properly recognized by alsa :

```
arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: imxaudiosph0645 [imx-audio-sph0645], device 0: imx-sph0645 snd-soc-dummy-dai-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

When recording with [arecord](https://linux.die.net/man/1/arecord) the sound is speed up by 2

When recording with [arecord](https://linux.die.net/man/1/arecord) -d (duration):

- the command duration is the double of the asked
- the recorded file has the correct duration but it is speed up by 2

I used an oscilloscope to check the BCLK clock and the frame (WS) clock :

```
time arecord -D hw:0,0 -r 48000 -f S32_LE -c 1 -d 5 -t wav -v 48000_32_1.wav
fsl_sai logs : clk_rate = 3072000, ratio = 1, ret = 0, freq = 3072000
Record time : 10s
File duration : 5s
Osciloscope BCLK clock 3.072 MHz, frame (WS) clock 48kHz
When opening the file in audacity, the configuration is correct but its length is 5 sec but it is speed up.
```

An example of sound : [here](https://community.nxp.com/pwmxy87654/attachments/pwmxy87654/imx-processors/171279/3/48000_32_1_wav.zip)

As I understand it the clocks are correct. The datasheet indicate "The Over Sampling Rate is fixed at 64 therefore the WS signal must be BCLK/64 and synchronized to the BCLK."

Maybe there is a configuration somewhere in alsa that I am not aware off ?

Let me know if I can add more informations.

Comment: This sounds like a clocking bug in the driver or in the driver configuration.

Comment: I guess, but the actual clock seams fine to me (not sure I understand it correctly).
For a 48000kHz recording, the WS clock has a 48000kHz period.
Unless it shouldn't ?

Comment: *48kHz not 48000kHz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and posted it on my initial post on the [nxp forum](https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/IMX8MM-SPH0645-I2S-microphone-speed-up-recordings/m-p/1267345#M173119).

The error was in the driver :

```
- snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk(cpu_dai, 1, bclk, SND_SOC_CLOCK_OUT);
+ snd_soc_dai_set_sysclk(cpu_dai, 0, bclk, SND_SOC_CLOCK_OUT);
```

The updated driver patch can be found [here](https://community.nxp.com/pwmxy87654/attachments/pwmxy87654/imx-processors/173119/1/003-sph0645-driver.patch)